# Fastest way to do a bulk fetch with PHP PDO and MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo, bulk

I'm using PHP with the PDO library to work with a MySQL database, and I am fetching several thousand rows from a database based on two of the fields. Specifically, I need rows corresponding to certain latitude-longitude pairs, if such points exist. Currently, I am making a prepared statement and executing it once per point/row. What is the fastest way to fetch many rows like this? Just use a bunch of OR's?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to answer to such a broad question.

The most general answer would be like this:

If you have to do this regularly - say, on a live site on each user's click - then, you have to reduce the number of parameters queried.
If it's just occasional operation - just leave it as is.

In other words, you don't need "fastest". You need "fast". Or even "reliable".

Comment: I do have to do it on a live web site, and I need to fetch all of the relevant rows from the database, there is no way to reduce it.

Comment: Well, if you need all these thousands to show to the user - there is no way. And no problem, as user will go nuts far faster than server. If you need these rows only for calculations - then calculate on the db server side